# Content-Type case sensitivity in RESTEasy 3

Tags: http-headers, content-type, resteasy

I am developing a RestEasy client to connect to a 3rd party REST service which has defined its own custom media types. A made up example is

```
application/vnd.abc.thirdPartyThing-v1+json
```

Note the uppercase P in thirdParty.

I am using RESTEasy 3.0.11 for my client implementation. At the point where I make a POST call to the service my code looks like

```
Response response = target.request()
        .post(Entity.<ThirdPartyThing>entity(
                thing,
                "application/vnd.abc.thirdPartyThing-v1+json"));
```

but RESTEasy sends to the server

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.abc.thirdpartything-v1+json
```

This is due to RESTEasy's MediaTypeHeaderDelegate class's toString() method, which lowercases the type and subtype [MediaTypeHeaderDelegate](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/3.0.11.Final/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/delegates/MediaTypeHeaderDelegate.java?av=f). This should be correct, or at least unimportant, as RFC-1341 states that Content-Type values are case-insensitive - [RFC-1341](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html)

Unfortunately the 3rd party service is checking the Content-Type in a case sensitive manner and so returning a 415 UNSUPPORTED MEDIA TYPE error. I've tested using curl which doesn't alter the content-type value and confirmed that it's a case issue. application/vnd.abc.thirdPartyThing-v1+json works, application/vnd.abc.thirdpartything-v1+json does not.

I'm in the process of raising a ticket, but in the meantime is there any way to override RESTEasy's default behaviour and send Content-Type headers without lowercasing the value?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce this behavior with RESTeasy 3.0.6.Final and would not expect it. Maybe you could check their [JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/resteasy) if this has already been discussed or open an issue. I once had problems on the server side because a 2.x version of RESTeasy was checking the charset attribute of the Content-Type header case-sensitive. This was also changed.

You could solve this problem by a really ugly workaround: Overwrite the header again in a [ClientRequestFilter](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-rev-a/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientRequestFilter.html).

```java
public class ContentTypeFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {

    private Map<String, String> contentTypes;

    public ContentTypeFilter() {
        contentTypes = new HashMap<>();
        contentTypes.put("text/foo", "text/Foo");
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        String contentType = requestContext.getHeaderString("Content-Type");
        if (contentTypes.containsKey(contentType)) {
            requestContext.getHeaders().putSingle("Content-Type", contentTypes.get(contentType));
        }
    }

}
```

Don't forget to register this Filter:

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(ContentTypeFilter.class);
```

Comment: Hi. First off, apologies for the long wait in a response. Partly due to this issue and partly due to realising that an old version of the Jersey Bundle was already used by the web application my code would be called from, I moved to using Jersey as the client and this issue did not exhibit. So it is specific to RESTEasy.

I finally got round to a simple example demonstrating the problem and added your ContentTypeFilter - works like a charm!

A really, really, ugly charm.

Thanks, answer accepted!